# Can't get environment variable from /etc/profile in GoLang

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables, sh

I've set some environment variables in /etc/profile, I can access them from bash, but for some reason I cant get them from Go.

/etc/profile:

```
...
TEST_ENV=test_me
```

I can access it from bash:

```
echo $TEST_ENV
test_me
```

I can't access this variable from GO

```
os.Getenv("TEST_ENV") // returns ""
```

If I list the available environment variables with

```
os.Environ()
```

I don't see the variable I'm looking for, but there a few variables that might help:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=root
LOGNAME=root
```

I guess my problem is related to different sessions and shells, so I even tried running

```
exec.Command("source /etc/profile")
```

and get the variables after, but it still returns nothing.

Can you give me some tips how to get environment variables if they're set in /etc/profile? I'd prefer getting them from that file, but if necessary, I can put the variables in a different place as well.

Comment: Environment variables are *not* "get [...] from [...] file". Never. These are environment variables and if the environment contains the variable than you can access it. You'll have to make sure your Go executable runs in an environment where TEST_ENV is set. If TEST_ENV is set in your local bash and you execute your Go binary from that bash the environment *will* be propagated to your binary and you *will* have access to it. Show how you execute your binary. Note that this problem is totally unrelated to Go: You are simply invoking your binary without a proper environment.

Answer (score 5):

When you set an environment variable in bash, by default it isn't exported. Only exported environment variables are passed along to processes created by the shell (i.e., programs that you run). Try `export TEST_ENV=test_me`.